# Issue with Facebook c# toolkit and authentication

Tags: facebook

I've used the excellent Facebook c# SDK http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ to integrate a website with facebook to get profile info etc but now I need to actually create a canvas app in an iframe. I'm just starting simply with the MVC sample app in the toolkit and have set the app id, key, secret, canvasPageUrl but when I go to the profile link (and the authentication stuff kicks in) facebook gives me a polite but confising error.

*To fix this error, please set your Connect URL in the application settings editor. Once it has been set, users will be redirected to that URL instead of this page after logging in.*

The thing is, this is using OAuth, not connect, and the connect URL doesn't even exist as a parameter in the application settings. I've dug around, found one php example with this problem but didn't seem appropriate as it was using a completely different auth method. Any ideas facebook pros?

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Basically, the SDK passes "fbconnect=1" in the login.php query string and that seems to break stuff. I chopped it off with Fiddler and the login proceeded normally. Later I just removed this query parameter from GetLoginUrl and everything is now peachy.

No idea why it still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the app migrations enabled on your facebook app? That is the main problem people have with authentication. [Getting Started](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Documentation)